# Error using worksheet.getrange.setvalues in Google Script. I have two arrays which appear to be identical. One works as expected, but the other fails

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

myVars is an array that holds variable names and their values.

Here is my code:

```
      var tmpArr = [];
      var tmpArrVals = "";
      
      for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        
        tmpArrVals = tmpArrVals + myVars[i][myCol] + ", ";
      }
        tmpArrVals = tmpArrVals.substr(0,tmpArrVals.length-2); //Trim last comma
        // Logger.log("tmpArrVals is " + tmpArrVals);

        
        tmpArr.push([tmpArrVals]);
      Logger.log('Contents of tmpArr are on next line.');
      Logger.log(tmpArr);
      
      var tstArr = [["Trip_Number", "Miles", "Empty_Miles", "Temp"]];
      Logger.log('Contents of tstArr are on next line');
      Logger.log(tstArr);

    wsDB.getRange(1,1,1,4).setValues(tmpArr);
    // wsDB.getRange(1,1,1,4).setValues(tstArr);
```

Here is the output from Logger:

```
3:36:28 PM  Notice  Execution started
3:36:28 PM  Info    Contents of tmpArr are on next line.
3:36:28 PM  Info    [[Trip_Number, Miles, Empty_Miles, Temp]]
3:36:28 PM  Info    Contents of tstArr are on next line
3:36:28 PM  Info    [[Trip_Number, Miles, Empty_Miles, Temp]]
3:36:29 PM  Error   
Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 4.
```

What baffles me is that if I change the last two lines of code so that I use tstArr instead of tmpArr, it works as expected and inserts values into the first four columns of the sheet, even though the contents of the two arrays appear to be exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that in your script, `tmpArr` is the array like `[["text value"]]`. By this, when you run the script of `wsDB.getRange(1,1,1,4).setValues(tmpArr)`, such error occurs. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. In order to remove this issue, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
tmpArr.push([tmpArrVals]);
```

#### To:

```
tmpArr.push(tmpArrVals.split(", "));
```

or

#### From:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  
  tmpArrVals = tmpArrVals + myVars[i][myCol] + ", ";
}
  tmpArrVals = tmpArrVals.substr(0,tmpArrVals.length-2); //Trim last comma
  // Logger.log("tmpArrVals is " + tmpArrVals);

  
  tmpArr.push([tmpArrVals]);
```

#### To:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  tmpArr.push(tmpArrVals + myVars[i][myCol]);
}
tmpArr = [tmpArr];
```

Comment: Both your recommendations worked. Thank you! I could not understand why I was getting the results I originally mentioned when both variables appeared to be identical. Ultimately, all I wanted was for it to work. I had spent about 20 hours trying different things before asking the question.

Comment: @RaifMT Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. As additional information, when such error occurs, for example, when you check `Logger.log(tmpArr.length)` and `Logger.log(tmpArr[0].length)`, you can confirm the numbers of the rows and columns. I thought that this information might be useful for checking the values for putting to Spreadsheet.